# How to stay in the same frame with Java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a Quiz game and my idea is that i have a main frame class with buttons and a label like this [image]

So when I click the Start button i want to stay in the same frame just delete all these buttons and label and replace them with the question and answers to it. How can I accomplish this? Read something about repaint() method and removeAll() but what is the best practice. I come up with this(dunno is it the right thing to do in the situation) but call removeAll() in the actionListener of the start button and create the new frame in this listener? Or can I make another class e.g called StartFrame and then in the actionListener of the start button call removeAll() and then `MainFrame.this = new StartFrame()` assuming that my class holding the initial state of the game like in the pic is called MainFrame

Comment: How about [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)?

Comment: Can I manage two JFrame objects with this CardLayout?

Comment: You don't want to create two JFrames. A frame is the entire window. You want to create JPanels for each "screen" of the game and switch between them.

Comment: Just work through the tutorial I linked to. You will get the idea,

Comment: I got the idea wrong with this JFrame. So in my class MainFrame which extends JFrame i can have the basic settings of the window. And i need other 2 classes which extends JPanel for the 2 scenes of the game and in these 2 classes i put everything and just switch between them with the card layout. Am i right?

Comment: And one last question. How to switch between cards? Because in the tutorial the thing that switches them is the combo box. In my case the thing that switches cards is Start button. Do I need this itemStateChanged method or I just need one ActionListener for the Start button to go to the other card?